# The value is not sent from dropdown to Express.js

Tags: html, node.js, express

I want to send the values of a form to Express.js to then save them in database. But the only value that is not reaching Express.js is the value in the select element. The form sends **two** things it sends an *excel file* and the value inside the *select element*. I even tried to console.log the req.body to see if the value is sent in the request body but it returns a void {} value. Here is the HTML.

```
<div class="w3-card-2 w3-display-middle" class="margin:auto">
<header class="w3-container w3-blue"><h4><b>Subir documento de Excel</b></h4></header>

<form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload" method="post">
    <br>
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Entidad financiera: </label>
    <select name="bancos" class="w3-select w3-border">       /* <---------- */
        <option value="noAsignado">No asignado</option>
        <option value="bhdLeon">BHD Leon</option>
        <option value="asociacionNacional">ASOCIACION NACIONAL DE AHORROS Y PRESTAMOS</option>
        <option value="pucmm">PUCMM</option>
        <option value="grupoAltus">GRUPO ALTUS</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input class="w3-display-bottommiddle" type="submit" value="Subir" name="submit">
</form>
```

Here the Node code:

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);    //  <---------------------
    var exceltojson;
    upload(req, res, function(err){
        if (err) {
            res.json({error_code:1,err_desc:err});
            return;
        }
        if(!req.file){
            res.json({error_code:1, err_desc:"No file passed"});
            return;
        }

        if(req.file.originalname.split('.')[req.file.originalname.split('.').length-1] === 'xlsx'){
            exceltojson = xlsxtojson;
        } else {
            exceltojson = xlstojson;
        }
        try {
            exceltojson({
                input: req.file.path,
                output: "./outPutJSON/output.json",
                lowerCaseHeaders: true
            }, function(err, result){
                if(err){
                    return res.json({error_code:1, err_desc:err, data: null});
                }
                res.json({datos:"Los datos fueron agregados exitosamente"});

                fs.readFile("./outPutJSON/output.json", 'utf8', async (err, fileContents) => {
                    if (err) {
                      console.error(err);
                      return;
                    }
                    try {
                      let data = JSON.parse(fileContents);
                      console.log(data);             //--------------HERE THE EXCEL FILE WHEN IS PARSED
                      io.emit('test event', 'Se han subido ' + data.length + ' casos' );

                      for(let cantidad = 0; cantidad < data.length; cantidad++){
                        var documento = data[cantidad];
                        if(documento.nombre === '' || documento.cedula === '' || documento.direccion === '') {
                            console.log('No se puede guardar este documento');
                        } else {
                            var mostrar = await incrementar();
                            documento.caso = mostrar;
                            documento.montoApoderado = data[cantidad]['monto apoderado'];
                            documento.numeroCliente = data[cantidad]['no.cliente'];
                            documento.numeroProducto = data[cantidad]['no.producto'];
                            let today = moment().format('YYYY M D');
                            documento.fechaCreado = today;
                            var mod = new model(documento);
                            await mod.save(documento);
                        }
                      }
                    } catch(err) {
                      console.error(err);
                    }
                  })

                });

                var fs = require('fs');
                try {
                    fs.unlinkSync(req.file.path)
                }catch(e){

                }
        } catch (e) {
            res.json({error_code:1, err_desc:"Corrupted excel file"});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `<form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload" method="post">`, try making your action attribute to be a relative url to your site or an absolute url

Comment: I tried it, but is the same...

Comment: Are you running `express.urlencoded()` middleware to parse the form elements into `req.body`?  If not, that's why `req.body` is empty.

Comment: Yes ---> app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-) Check that your express.js use the next sentences before calling the router methods:

```
app.use(bodyParser);
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); // support encoded bodies
```

2-) You don't have an **ID attribute** attached to your  tag and **NAME attributes** to select options (although the name is the one necessary for the server-side... :/)

You need to re-write your js code:

```
    <select id="banks" name="bancos" class="w3-select w3-border">       /* <---------- */
        <option name="noAsignado" value="noAsignado">No asignado</option>
        <option name="bhdLeon" value="bhdLeon">BHD Leon</option>
        <option name="asociacionNacional" value="asociacionNacional">ASOCIACION NACIONAL DE AHORROS Y PRESTAMOS</option>
        <option name="pucmm" value="pucmm">PUCMM</option>
        <option name="grupoAltus" value="grupoAltus">GRUPO ALTUS</option>
    </select>
```

3-) Maybe you are checking the body before going through the **next()** function. Try before executing the handler and there, check the **req.body** again. :)

Best regards.